# Where could I ask about the nutritional value of something?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

There's something very specific (a specific part of a fruit) whose nutritional value I'm curious about yet I've been unable to find information regarding it, so I was thinking I'd ask about it here on Stack Exchange to see if someone has any ideas. Where might I ask this?

Comment: Would your question [fit this criteria](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/nutrient-composition/info) for on-topic on cooking?

Comment: [Also here](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/790/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-nutritional-info).

Comment: @Ollie I think it'd be off-topic there as the thing I'm wondering has little relation to a fitness programme.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm not sure, even after reading that. My question is about a specific part of a fruit, and to me it does not come off as clear whether that is okay to ask there.

Comment: In that case I don't think we have anywhere where your question would work. That does happen sometimes.

Comment: There is a biology stack which does have a food tag but it has no wiki and I never visit biology so I am not sure whether you would strike lucky there.

Comment: To those downvoting: may I know what's wrong with the question?